# MYSQL Server 5.6 + Visual Studio 2013 C++ setting

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I am a beginner of using C++ on MYSQL. I face a setting problem. I tried to follow step by step for this website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/, but I can't follow it after step5. I have tried other solutions but still not success. Can anyone please provides the steps for me to follow? Thanks.

What I have installed now:

- Visual Studio Community 2013
- MYSQL Sever 5.6
- boost_1_58_0
- Connector.C++ 1.1